# JavaScript Object retrieve value dynamically

Tags: javascript

Sorry if it sounds like a stupid question

I have this following JavaScript object:

```
data = {
    "Max" : 100
}
```

This same object can also have the following form:

```
data = {
    "January": {"Max" : 100}
}
```

I want to use one same `function` to retrieve the value of `Max` if given the two forms

And it made me wonder if it is possible to write a conditional expressions directly in the `[]` when you write the values you want to retrieve? Is this following expression allowed in JavaScript? Something like this:

```
data[monthly ? 'month' : '']
```

Of course I tried it and it doesn't work. But is there another way to do such a thing in a line? `monthly` is a boolean

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following script to do that, I have added some comments to make it clear

```js
var data1 = {
  "Max" : 100
}

var data2 = {
  "January": {"Max" : 100}
}

// storing the months in an array to loop over and see if the current key is a month
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

function getMax(data) {
  // if the key `Max` exists in data then just get the value of `data.Max` else loop over the months, and see if one of the months is a key and stores a truthy value, in this case it stores an object, so that's what we want and then get it's .Max value
  return "Max" in data ? data.Max : data[months.filter(m => data[m] ? m : "")[0]].Max;
}

console.log(getMax(data1));
console.log(getMax(data2));
```

Comment: excellent use of the in operator, a lot of people would probably go with just `months.Max` but this can behave weirdly if you have falsy values

Comment: @Zer0 Thank you for your feedback, I like to always write good code

Comment: This is good, But i want to get specific month and not check every month object to see if there's a "truthy" value

Comment: Pls update your question, my answer is about the current question, if you want me to update it, you need to update your question, and pls give the expected input and output as well

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
let data = {
  "Max": 100
};

const getMax = (data) => {
  //check if "Max" is available in the `data`, if so return `data.Max` else 
  //get values of the keys in the object using `Object.values` and 
  //retreive `Max` from the array
  return data.Max ? data.Max : Object.values(data)[0].Max
}

console.log(getMax(data));

data = {
  "January": {
    "Max": 200
  }
}

console.log(getMax(data));
```

There's yet another way of achieving this using [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`Optional Chaining`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

```js
let data = {
  Max: 100,
};

const getMax = (data = {}) => {
  return data.Max ? data.Max : Object.values(data).find(({ Max }) => Max)?.Max;
};

console.log(getMax(data));

data = {
  January: { Max: 200 },
};

console.log(getMax(data));
```